# Adding a CSS class to Google DoubleClick For Publishers Ad

Tags: css, double-click, ads

As the title suggests I am currently looking for a way to add a CSS class to the ad divs on my site provided by Google's DoubleClick For Publishers.

I have a sidebar on the site containing my ads which I wish to display in such a way that they have a 10px margin separating each ad.

I have a workaround at the mo by targeting every google div in the stylesheet and setting the margin-top to 10px. So:

```
#google_ads_div_MySite_Home_MPU1_300x250_ad_container, #google_ads_div_MySite_SiteWide_LargeButton1_300x100, #google_ads_div_MCV_SiteWide_LargeButton2_300x100{margin-top:10px;}
```

However this is incredibly messy and involves meticulously checking the stylesheet to check every single ad has been defined. Across a large site this can be a nightmare.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the id of the ad div with your css, apply your CSS to the child of the container of the ads.

Your html probably look like

```
<div>
    <div id="google_ads_div_MySite_Home_MPU1_300x250_ad_container">some ad</div>
    <div id="google_ads_div_MCV_SiteWide_LargeButton2_300x100">some other ad</div>
</div>
```

just change it to

```
<div class="ad_container>
    <div id="google_ads_div_MySite_Home_MPU1_300x250_ad_container">some ad</div>
    <div id="google_ads_div_MCV_SiteWide_LargeButton2_300x100">some other ad</div>
</div>
```

and in css :

```
.ad_container div {margin-top:10px}
```